# Angular Location service normalize does not prepend base href

Tags: angular

I have specified

```
<base href="/abcd">
```

in `<head>` of my index.html and I am calling

```
location.normalize('/logoff')
```

I expect the result to be something like

> http://localhost:xxxx/abcd/logoff

but I get

> http://localhost:xxxx/logoff

as if the normalize method doesn't take into account `<base href....>`

Although when I use the Go method on location service `Location.go('/logoff')` it works correctly and navigates to

> http://localhost:xxxx/abcd/logoff

Is this expected behaviour. I understand that the default location strategy is PathLocationStrategy. Even then I have explicitly configured PathLocationStrategy and still I am not getting the expected result.

Can anyone please explain or confirm that my understanding of Location.normalize is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So rather than using

> Location.normalize

in order to get base address prepended

> Location.[prepareExternalUrl](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareExternalUrl) should be used.